# Modern day vs modern-day in a sentence

Tags: grammar, hyphens

I'm preparing for academic IELTS by writing some essays and then correcting those using a grammar correction app.

In the following sentence,

> ...as opposed to the modern day where the numbers are more or less
> equal

The app suggests using "modern-day" (hyphen added) instead of "modern day". Why is it so and is it critical?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy answer look it up in the dictionary.

modern-day: adjective: relating to people or things from modern times and not from a time in the past: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/modern-day)

> Modern-day engines are so much more efficient.